# How to write to textfile in For loop, vb.net

Tags: for-loop

I have 3 string variables already declared and with values set. I want to write these 3 strings to a text file in a For loop, one string for each pass of the loop. I can't figure out how to get vb.net to understand that I want to add an integer counter to a string, and for it to understand that is not a literal string, but one of the 3 string variables that are already declared and have values.

sample code --->

```
Dim writer As New StreamWriter("c:\temp\test_out.txt")  
Dim datastr1 As String
Dim datastr2 As String
Dim datastr3 As String
datastr1 = "test string 1"
datastr2 = "test string 2"
datastr3 = "test string 3"


Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To 3
    writer.WriteLine("datastr" & i)
Next i
```

The result is:

```
datastr1
datastr2
datastr3
```

But I want the result to be:

```
test string 1
test string 2
test string 3
```

Thank you for helping me.

Comment: You need to contain them inside an array, so you can loop through it. Right now, they are individual strings.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Dim datastr() As String = {"test string 1", 
                             "test string 2", 
                             "test string 3"}
    ' Loop over each element with For Each.
    For Each str As String In datastr
        writer.WriteLine(str)
    Next
```